# Slices & Extract Assets, or Copy CSS & paragraph styles for retina web designs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, slices

I'm trying to figure out how Adobe wants me to work in Photoshop when producing website designs.

Extract Assets is useful for fixed-size objects to produce 50% & 100% assets. 200% png output results in anti-aliasing even from vector shapes. Please correct me if I'm wrong but this seemed to be the case. Slicing is useful for elements on the site that may have variable height/width needing end-caps and repeat-x or repeat-y images e.g. buttons and nav-bars.

If I need to work at 2x resolution for retina, using Extract Assets and Slices, my paragraph and character styles dimensions are doubled, as are the dimensions of all my objects. This makes the Copy CSS a bit pointless - double height, width, margin, padding, shadow blur etc.

Should I be designing at 2x resolution and extracting and slicing, or at 1x and using Copy CSS, exporting paragraphing styles? Or something inbetween?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you should get anti-aliasing from shape paths. However, we are investigating why some of the illustrator smart objects do not render correctly.

Have you tried out our [Creative Cloud Extract service](https://assets.adobe.com/link/b7300f48-fd51-4a4c-acb9-adb18fbfa02d?section=extract)? I feel that is a much better way to get measurements and values out of a PSD as it offers a lot more than CopyCSS in Photoshop does. If you save your files into Creative Cloud, you can automatically start using it when you go to assets.adobe.com

In general the recommendation is to design at 2x and then extract assets out for 1x.

--

*I am a Product Manager at Adobe looking after Extract Assets UI*